# monorepo with vue-cli 3 and lerna

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli-3, lerna

I'm trying to create a monorepo using vue-cli 3 and lerna. I now have two packages:

`common` and `app`. Both `common` and `app` use `Vue` and import it. `common` has its main set like this. `"main": "dist/common.umd.min.js"`

When I import `common` in `app`, the process crashes with this error message trying to process `common.umd.min.js`:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Even running with `node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js serve` throws this error.

If I use `"main": "src/main.ts"`, the build process works, but when I use `vue-cli-service build`, `Vue` is bundled twice, once for `common` and once for `app`.

Answer (score 1):

Like you noticed, you are bundling Vue twice in your app. This is likely because you are including Vue as a dependency of both your `common` and `app` packages.

Have the `app` package be the only package that depends on Vue, and then you can make your `common` package export a [Vue plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html). Your `app` package can then install the `common` plugin like so:

```js
// main.js (in the app package)

import Vue from 'vue';
import plugin from 'my-common-package';

Vue.use(plugin);
```

I'm unsure of what is causing the out of memory error, but only using one Vue instance is a good start.